# Conceptual blending

Tags: linguistics

Is there a mathematical formalization of conceptual blending? I know that feature structures in linguistics or frames in AI can be combined using unification which is a special (simple) case of conceptual blending. How can more complex blends be formalized? To stay in the domain of linguistics, complex predicates (e.g., I made her cry) are said to involve conceptual blending that can't be formalized as unification.

Comment: Can you provide a basic source on conceptual blending? It's not completely clear what you're asking. Is it an AI question or a linguistics question?